# yui imagecropper appears under the image?

Tags: javascript, html, css, yui

So I am working on a simple image cropping function using pre-built Yahoo UI. However, it seems the cropping box or whatever it is called lies under the image, or maybe it's just transparent.

Here is my code, you can just copy and paste to inspect.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/assets/skins/sam/resize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/assets/skins/sam/imagecropper.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/resize/assets/skins/sam/resize.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/fonts/fonts-min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/imagecropper/assets/skins/sam/imagecropper.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/yahoo-dom-event/yahoo-dom-event.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/element/element-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/dragdrop/dragdrop-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/resize/resize-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/imagecropper/imagecropper-min.js"></script>
<img id="yui_img" src="http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/imagecropper/assets/yui.jpg">
<script>
(function(){var crop = new YAHOO.widget.ImageCropper('yui_img');})();
</script>
```

Here is the URL to the demo Yahoo provides
http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/imagecropper/simple_crop_clean.html

Please help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention, if you run my code, though the crop box is invisible, the cursor does change. However, the box is very tiny, like 6px * 6px on the top-left corner of the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code that was working for me

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>


    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Simple Crop Interface</title>

<style type="text/css">
/*margin and padding on body element
  can introduce errors in determining
  element position and are not recommended;
  we turn them off as a foundation for YUI
  CSS treatments. */
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
</style>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/resize/assets/skins/sam/resize.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/fonts/fonts-min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/imagecropper/assets/skins/sam/imagecropper.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/yahoo-dom-event/yahoo-dom-event.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/element/element-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/dragdrop/dragdrop-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/resize/resize-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/imagecropper/imagecropper-min.js"></script>

<!--there is no custom header content for this example-->

</head>

<body class="yui-skin-sam">


<h1>Simple Crop Interface</h1>

<div class="exampleIntro">
    <p>This example shows how to make an image croppable.</p>

</div>

<!--BEGIN SOURCE CODE FOR EXAMPLE =============================== -->


<img id="yui_img" src="http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/imagecropper/assets/yui.jpg">

<script>
(function() {
    var Dom = YAHOO.util.Dom,
        Event = YAHOO.util.Event;

    var crop = new YAHOO.widget.ImageCropper('yui_img');
})();
</script>

<!--END SOURCE CODE FOR EXAMPLE =============================== -->
</body>
</html>
```

When I removed the last script ie

```
<script>
(function() {
    var Dom = YAHOO.util.Dom,
        Event = YAHOO.util.Event;

    var crop = new YAHOO.widget.ImageCropper('yui_img');
})();
</script>
```

This code then the box dissappeared please check with your code. Maybe the javascript is essential or maybe ur missing some thing else. Better to keep all the js and css and try debugging removing one by one. You will get to know the specific point. And my code is hopefully working please let me know if it isn't. :)

Comment: I put the importing script and css part inside body tag in the first place. Now it works like a charm! thanx!